# User session timeout force logoff

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, session-timeout, logoff

I have been doing a little research on how to make a script using vbs or batch to set a session time limit for users logging onto a specific set of computers linked through Group Policy.
I am not familiar with log off or timed scripts, I can make the simplest batch script to log the current user off a machine. The problem I get to is not being able to set a timed session, or running the log-off script due to the time limit.
I researched setting it through group policy, then came up with the idea of linking a script to a group policy in the start up for users on the certain set of computers. 
I found a vbs by googling key phrases but I am not sure exactly how to implement it with the log off script or how to make it begin its count down

```
echo.
echo Waiting For thirty minutes...     
TIMEOUT /T 1800 /NOBREAKS    
echo.    
echo (logoff)    
echo.
pause >nul
```

The log off script that I was planning on using goes along the lines of:

```
shutdown -l -f -t 30 -c "Your 30 minute session is over."
```

But I cant get the comment to display and the 30 second time doesn’t take affect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Thank you rd1966, I was able to come up with a little batch script the only issue I am now having is to link it to GPO to run on the User Logon/Logoff. For anyone looking for something like what I needed here is a way to schedule a task to run in 30 minutes to reboot the computer unless the user logs off. Here is what I came up with: 
First off the script to enable the service and create the task- schtasks /delete /tn Logoff /f 
sc config schedule start= auto
sc start schedule
schtasks /create /tn "Logoff" /tr E:\Logoff.bat /sc minute /mo 30 /ru SYSTEM

Comment: ---I had to add the removal of the task in the beginning in case someone else logged in before it stopped the task. 
Then to reboot the computer- 
schtasks /delete /tn Logoff /f
shutdown -r -t 25 -f  
--- Once again I added the removal of the task so the comp wont keep rebooting. What I want to do with GPO is to put the first script linked to the logon of a user then to put a removal of the task on the logoff, the only thing I cant do is figure out what to put under the parameters.... any help would be greatly appreciated!ppreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about somthing like this?

```
Set oSystems = GetObject("winmgmts:{(Shutdown)}//./root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where Primary=true") 
For Each oSystem in oSystems    
    oSystem.Win32ShutdownTracker 3600,"Logging off...",0,4
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but here you go anyway:

have a .vbs file called invis.vbs and place it in the Startup directory of the user you want to be limited.

It should contain the following (replace #username# with the Username):

```
wscript.exe “C:\Users\#username#\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Start-up\invis.vbs” “C:\SessionLimit.bat”
```

Now save the below as a batch file called SessionLimit.bat in the C:\ Directory.
It should contain the following:

```
@echo off
timeout 1800 /nobreak 
shutdown /l ;;Replace this comment with /f if you want the log off to be forced without the Do you want to save your work interruption window.
```